# jQuery: replace all yyyy-mm-dd dates on page to dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: jquery

here's what I have so far but I don't know swap out the original with a `dd-mm-yyyy`

```
  var divs = $("div,td").filter(function(){
            return /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/.test($(this).text());
  });
```

Comment: My advise would be to look in to http://momentjs.com/ its a time framework which really can help in time problems with jQuery/Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

although doing the same with core Javascript is more easy yet if you want it in jQuery only then try this

```
 $("td").filter(function(){
           var $txt = $(this).text();
           var $m = $txt.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/);
           var $new = $m[3] + "-" + $m[2] + "-" + $m[1];
           return $(this).text($new);
           //or 
           //return $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/, "$3-$2-$1"));
  });
```

[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fs3rA/1/)

Comment: hmmmm the $m is null for me